# How to list most visited links in Drupal from different pages?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have made one block for most visited links (Top Links) in my drupal website but I dont know how to list most visited from different pages. For example, if I have created a page named drupal and within that page i have added some content with some title, then i have to examine and count those titles and list the top visited title from each and every page on my homepage(only one from each and every title that is most visited) and list them on my homepage block.
Could anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the statistics module is enabled. Visit /admin/config/system/statistics (Drupal 7) and make sure Count content views is enabled (ticked).
Use views to create a block the usual way; for example add a field like Content: Title. Then make sure you add a sort criteria of Content statistics: Total views (desc).

Comment: I have already done that but the thing is that I want to filter the view according to other content types which I have created. So is there any way to configure that, there is one by creating content filter group but I did that too, but with no results. Thanks!